# Surjection of map to n-Sphere

Tags: general-topology

Consider the map $f\colon S^n \times S^m \times [0,1] \rightarrow S^{n+m+1}$ defined by $f(p,q,t) = p \cos(\frac{\pi}{2}t) +q \sin(\frac{\pi}{2}t)$ where $p \in S^n$, $q \in S^m$ and $t \in[0,1]$. Show this map is surjective, where $n,m \in \mathbb{R}$

I have been able to show it when $n=m=0$ and for $n=0, m=1$, but I am having problems to generalize it.

Edit: Following Ted's suggestion, I think about $p,q$ as $p\in S^n\subset \Bbb R^{n+1}\times \{0\}\subset\Bbb R^{n+1}\times\Bbb R^{m+1} = \Bbb R^{n+m+2}$. So basically the map is similar to a linear combination of points

Comment: You should add that you're thinking of $p\in S^n\subset \Bbb R^{n+1}\times \{0\}\subset\Bbb R^{n+1}\times\Bbb R^{m+1} = \Bbb R^{n+m+2}$, etc.

Comment: What are you having trouble with? Do you see that it maps to $S^{n+m+1}$?  If you start with an arbitrary point $x=(x_1,\dots,x_{n+1},x_{n+2},\dots,x_{n+m+2})\in S^{n+m+1}$, can you figure out what $p$ and $q$ to choose?

Comment: Yes, it is a linear combination of vectors, but geometrically you're joining two points by a great circle arc.

Comment: I understand that it maps to $S^{n+m+1}$. I was thinking about taking p as the north pole of $S^{n+m+1}$ and the other point in the equator. I mean, setting the first $n+1$ coordinates to 0, following what I did for $n=0, m=1$. In that case, it was basically connect two points in a plane by an arc. Doing it for a quarter of the hypersphere should be enough

Comment: It might help you to work more explicitly with vectors $(p,0)$ and $(0,q)$.

Comment: Is choosing the north pole of the hypersphere as one of the points a good idea or I am in the wrong direction?

Comment: No, you have a sphere in place of $S^0$ and a sphere in place of $S^1$ in your model. I think you should think about the questions and hints I've explicitly given you.

Comment: I was thinking in the exercise in the wrong way. For each point I the hypersphere I have to choose 2 points, but for the others, I can change them. So let the point in the hypersphere be $(a,b,c...r,s,t)$. This is equal to $(a,b,c,..,0,0) + (0,0...,r,s,t)$. i.e, the first point has its first $n+1$ coordinates non 0, and the opposite for the other, its last coordinates non zero. And think about that vectors as the vectors in the sphere, choosing the correct one to match the cosine and sine. Also, the extra dimension should be solved when I collapse some points. I'll continue working on it

Comment: I ended up saying the following. Let $(p',q') \in S^{n+m+1}$. Let $(p,0) \in S^n\subset \Bbb R^{n+1}\times \{0\}$ as above, and similarly, $(0,q) \in S^n\subset \Bbb R^{nm+1}\times \{0\}$. Set $(p',q') = (p,0) \cos(\frac{\pi}{2}t) +(0,q) \sin(\frac{\pi}{2}t)$

Comment: This gives me a system of equations, with $n+m+2$ equations (one for each coordinate if you write it down) and $n+m+2$ incognites. $n+m+1$ come from the coordinates $(p,0), (q,0)$ and the last one is the parameter $t$. Then I think I have a system of equations which is determinated and compatible (I guess), and solving it I get the points I were looking for (and also $t$), so the application is surjective. I don't post is an answer, because I am not 100% sure. Hopefully someone gives me some feedback

Comment: Don't think about systems of equations. Think about how $p'$ and $p$ ($q'$ and $q$) are related for things to live where they belong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a point $(x,y) \in S^{n+m+1}$, where $x \in \mathbb R^{n+1}, y \in \mathbb R^{m+1}$. We are looking for a solution $(p,q,t) \in S^n \times S^m \times [0,1]$ of the two equations
$$\cos(\frac{\pi}{2} t) p = x, \sin  (\frac{\pi}{2} t) q = y .$$
Note that $\cos(\frac{\pi}{2} t), \sin(\frac{\pi}{2} t) \in [0,1]$ for $t \in[0,1]$. Taking the norm, we see that a necessary condition for $t$ is
$$(*) \quad \cos(\frac{\pi}{2} t) = \cos(\frac{\pi}{2} t) \lVert p \rVert = \lVert \cos(\frac{\pi}{2} t) p \rVert = \lVert x \rVert , \sin(\frac{\pi}{2} t) = \sin(\frac{\pi}{2} t) \lVert q \rVert = \lVert \sin(\frac{\pi}{2} t) q \rVert = \lVert y \rVert .$$

But $\lVert x \rVert^2 +  \lVert y \rVert^2 = \lVert (x,y) \rVert^2 = 1$. Thus $(\lVert x \rVert,\lVert y \rVert) \in S^1$. Hence there is a unique $\tau \in [0,2\pi)$ such that $(\lVert x \rVert,\lVert y \rVert) = (\cos \tau,\sin \tau)$. Since $\lVert x \rVert,\lVert y \rVert \ge 0$, we see that $\tau \in [0,\pi/2]$. Hence $t = \frac{2\tau}{\pi} \in [0,1]$ is the unique solution of $(*)$.

Moreover, if $x \ne 0$, we necessarily have $p = \frac{x}{\lVert x \rVert}$, and if $y \ne 0$, we necessarily have $q = \frac{y}{\lVert y \rVert}$.

By inserting we easily verify

1. If $x,y \ne 0$, then $f(\frac{x}{\lVert x \rVert},\frac{y}{\lVert y \rVert},\frac{2\tau}{\pi}) = (x,y)$.
2. If $x = 0$, then $\lVert y \rVert = 1$ and $\tau = \frac{\pi}{2}$. Let $p \in S^{n+1}$ be arbitrary. Then $f(p,y,1) = (0,y) = (x,y)$.
3. If $y = 0$, then $\lVert x \rVert = 1$ and $\tau = 0$. Let $q \in S^{m+1}$ be arbitrary. Then $f(x,q,0) = (x,0) = (x,y)$.